# Is the whenChanged Active Directory attribute editable?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap

I've been searching for tools to change Active Directory object attributes, and I noticed the tools and articles and found so far are explicitly not mentioning capability to edit the `whenChanged` attribute.

It would be logical to assume that it's not editable at all, since it would reduce the value of system auditing services provided by Active Directory.

So the question: is the `whenChanged` attribute on an Active Directory object directly writable/editable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `whenChanged` attribute is [system-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680921(v=vs.85).aspx); it can never be updated by user action.  You'd need to directly manipulate the database to change it.

Comment: I need 4 more points to upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

No, System-only attributes are not writable.  I also don't think there would be a reasonable business need to do so.